# What transformation to use in Dataflow to merge csv files with differing columns while loading them to BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a few csv files that I need to have a single table for. The issue is that the files have different columns - most of the columns are same, except 1 or at max 2 that change. Loading them into *BigQuery* from *GCS* using the graphical user interface gives incorrect results or just fails altogether. Moreover whenever an `YEAR` column is missing, then I'd like to provide a value manually for the whole file.
We can look at the following 2 files for demo -

**file1.csv** -

```
ITEM,TYPE,COLOR,YEAR
a,1,red,2010
b,2,blue,2010
c,3,green,2010
```

**file1.csv** where `YEAR` would be 2012 (the location of the missing column need not be at the end) -

```
ITEM,TYPE,COLOR
d,3,yellow
e,2,orange
f,1,cyan
```

Combined files into a single BigQuery table would look like -

```
+------+------+--------+------+
| ITEM | TYPE | COLOR  | YEAR |
+------+------+--------+------+
| a    |    1 | red    | 2010 |
| b    |    2 | blue   | 2010 |
| c    |    3 | green  | 2010 |
| d    |    3 | yellow | 2012 |
| e    |    2 | orange | 2012 |
| f    |    1 | cyan   | 2012 |
+------+------+--------+------+
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to do transformations like these (preferably using the Python SDK of Apache Beam?) while reading files from GCS and loading them as tables in BigQuery.

Is it better to use SDK or to provide a custom template file to run from GCS(as the Dataflow GUI shows)?

Any resource on it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/dataflow-python-examples) where you can find a guide using the Dataflow python API to ingest data from a CSV file and write it into BigQuery.

Here's another [guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/dataflow-python-examples#transforming-data-in-dataflow) that also ingest data from CSV file and performs basic data type transformations by translating the date format from the source data into a date format BigQuery accepts.

Regarding your question "Is it better to use SDK or to provide a custom template file to run from GCS(as the Dataflow GUI shows)?
I believe this a matter of personal preferences,  none it's better than the other one.

Having said that, please feel free to follow up this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch) wich contains several Google-provided batch templates.